# What's the difference between a Name and a FriendlyName?

Tags: java, soap, saml

I've started to work with SOAP and SAML, and when I create an attribute, I'm wondering what's the difference with setting a Name or setting a Friendly Name to an Attribute.

```
XSAny value = (XSAny) builder.buildObject(AttributeValue.DEFAULT_ELEMENT_NAME);
value.setTextContent("Supervalue");

Attribute attribute2 = create(Attribute.class, Attribute.DEFAULT_ELEMENT_NAME);
attribute2.setName("MyName");
attribute2.getAttributeValues().add(value);
attribute2.setFriendlyName("My Friendly Name?");
```

Comment: Doesn't the API documentation of class `Attribute` explain what the `setName` and `setFriendlyName` do?

Comment: @Jasper. from documentation: setName-> Sets the name of this attribute. setFriendlyName -> Sets the friendly name of this attribute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SAML_2.0), it would appear that the name is a GUID and that the friendlyName is a human-readable identifier.

I'm not sure if either or both need to be unique. I'm not sure if the Name has certain constraints on it. My hunch is that FriendlyName doesn't have too many constraints, and is designed to be user-friendly. I hope this helps :)